# why in BIC Bayesian information criterion we ignore items independent of N

Tags: model-selection, bic

I wonder why BIC is defined in a way where items independent of N are dropped. In other words, why in the following image those in equation 6 that don't vary as N grows are ignored in equation 7. Is this because when N approaches infinite only those dependent on N dominate? The source of the image is [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture16.pdf)

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about BIC but that's exactly what's written there

Comment: Dropping the terms that don't involve the sample size  is another approximation on top of the Laplace approximation. See for example [The unit information prior and its BIC approximation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26339/237901) and [Why doesn't the formula for the BIC include  in it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/479745/237901)